# Can CSS be used for putting commas in input fields?

Tags: html, css, forms

Can CSS be used put commas into an input field so that when the user types in, for example, 1000000 the number in the field shows up as 100,000?

Comment: @theBartender You want to do it with CSS ? because it's so easy with javascript.

Comment: No, you would need Javascript to do this.